# How can I solve map function problem in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

I am fetching data and I am passing props to other components. But in one of the child components I can't using map() function. I am getting *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')*. I think this is an asynchronous data problem. But I can't solve it.

Here is my child component:

```
function WeeklyForecast({data}) {

      console.log(data);
      
      return (
        <div className='WeeklyForecast'>
          <div className="Prev-Btn">
            <button>&lt;</button>
          </div>
          <div className="Forecast-List">
          {data.map((forecast, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
    
                <p>{forecast[0]}</p>
    
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="Next-Btn">
            <button>&gt;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )

}
```

There are my error and browser console results without map() function:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't pass in null or undefined as the data prop to the child component. You didn't give us enough code to work with but you probably want to change something like this `const [data, setData] = useState()` in the parent component to `const [data, setData] = useState([])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem you are facing is you are trying to map over the data before it becomes available (as per your logs) what you want to do is make sure the data is available before blindly mapping over it... You can do such by checking that the data is available. You can learn more about conditional rendering [here](https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering).
Just add a && (AND) clause to your statement, so that you can guarantee that data is not undefined and available.
This will give you the ability to wait for the data to load from your server. 
So the statement becomes `data && data.map(...)`
So your code will look like the following.

```
function WeeklyForecast({data}) {

      console.log(data);
      
      return (
        <div className='WeeklyForecast'>
          <div className="Prev-Btn">
            <button>&lt;</button>
          </div>
          <div className="Forecast-List">
          {data && data.map((forecast, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
    
                <p>{forecast[0]}</p>
    
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="Next-Btn">
            <button>&gt;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )

}
```